Decorations on the patch
Hi I'm stuck at finding the solution to "embed" arrowhead on the patch plot which would indicate loop flow direction. The decorations with post action will not work (for apparent reason).
Is there any trick how to acomplish it?
I tried:

adding the arrows manually onto the background layer (as I couldn't find the way to draw only the arrow head the finished positioning was clunky at best and the result was mediocre)
spath and remembering the path (but the path is empty, duh)

Current code to draw the hysteresis loop:
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{babel, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, spath3}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\iflanguage{czech}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
    guide/.style={thin, dashed, themeGrey},
    flow arrow/.style={-{Latex[scale=0.75]}, thick, themeBlue!60, shorten >=1pt, } %shorten <=3pt
]

\definecolor{themeBlue}{RGB}{1, 103, 143}
\definecolor{themeOrange}{RGB}{221, 109, 16}
\definecolor{themeTeal}{RGB}{18, 54, 69}
\definecolor{themeGrey}{RGB}{120, 121, 124}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground} 

\begin{axis}[
    width=10cm, height=10cm, samples = 100,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5,
    enlargelimits=false, clip=false, 
    axis on top, axis lines*=middle, axis line style = {semithick, -latex},
    yticklabel style={text width=1.75em, align=left},
%
    xlabel={$\text{H}$},
    xtick={1.5, 4}, 
    xticklabels={$\text{+H}_{\text{c}}$, $\text{+H}_{\text{m}}$},
    extra x ticks={-4, -1.5},
    extra x tick labels={$\text{-H}_{\text{m}}$, $\text{-H}_{\text{c}}$},
    extra x tick style={
        xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}
    },
%
    ylabel={$\text{B}$},
    ytick={2.5, 4}, 
    yticklabels={$\text{+B}_{\text{r}}$, $\text{+B}_{\text{m}}$},
    extra y ticks={-4, -2.5},
    extra y tick labels={$\text{-B}_{\text{m}}$, $\text{-B}_{\text{r}}$},
    extra y tick style={
        yticklabel style={xshift=5ex, text width=1.5em, align=left}
    },
%
    every axis plot/.style={thick},
    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south,},
]

\addplot [mesh, patch type=quadratic spline, themeBlue, dashed] coordinates {
   (0,0) (4,4) (1.5,1)% first segment
};

\addplot [patch, patch type=quadratic spline, themeBlue] coordinates {
   (-4,-4) (-1.5,0) (-2.5,-2.8) % first segment
   (-1.5,0) (4,4) (0,2.5) % second segment
};

\addplot [mark=*, only marks, ultra thin, themeBlue] plot coordinates {
    (4, 4) (-4, -4)
    (1.5, 0) (-1.5, 0)
    (0, -2.5) (0, 2.5)
};

\addplot [patch, patch type=quadratic spline, themeBlue] coordinates {
     (-4,-4) (1.5,0) (0,-2.5) % left, right, middle-> first segment
     (1.5,0) (4,4) (2.5,2.8) % left, right, middle-> second segment
};

% Adding arrows to indicate flow direction
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\addplot [guide] plot coordinates { (0, 4) (4, 4) (4, 0) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



